# Generate int of numbers between 1 and n with dynamic n

Tags: c

I am struggling with an algorithm to print numbers between 1 and a dynamic variable n into an int.

```
int n = // dynamic value
int i = 0;
int output[n];

for(i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    output[i] = i;
}
```

However, as n is dynamic, the code won't compile.

Any help would be much appreciated - thanks in advance.

Comment: The code that won't compile is the `int output[n]`, yes? You'd need to dynamically allocate memory with `malloc`.

Comment: You must be using an ancient compiler. This is perfectly valid in C99.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to allocate a buffer, or dynamic-sized array, with [`malloc`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/malloc):

```
int n = // whatever
int i = 0;
int* output = NULL;

// Allocate the buffer
output = malloc(n * sizeof(int));
if (!output) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Failed to allocate.\n");
    exit(1);
}

// Do the work with the array
for(i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    output[i] = i;
}

// Finished with the array
free(output);
```

`output` is a pointer to the beginning of the buffer you allocated, and you can treat it as an array of `n` `ints`.

When you're finished with the array, you need to de-allocate the memory with [`free`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/free).

Comment: Or you could compile with -std=c99 which allow this

Comment: @benjarobin I've heard about it, but never used this feature. Is it a stack or heap allocation?

Comment: stack : how do you free the memory if it was heap ?
This feature is very useful, but can be very dangerous

Comment: c99 will allocate from the stack. Of course, you need to have a valid value in 'n' first, or it won't work.

Comment: Oh, and you shouldn't cast the output from malloc.

Comment: @benjarobin I assumed as much. I'll have to play that, thanks for explaining.

Comment: @MatsPetersson Why not? If I recall it will issue a warning otherwise as the return value of `malloc` is a `void*`.

Comment: And in C, a void * can be converted to any other pointer without warning or error. You weren't using C++ mode in the compiler, by any chance? If you, by accident, have forgotten to include the header that provides malloc, and you are running on a machine where pointers are larger than int, you will get a more notable error or warning for malloc() not having the right return type (compiler defaults to int), rather than an accidental trunkation of the upper part of the pointer - which you only discover when you've run more than 10000 iterations of some loop, and run out of the first 4GB ram...

Comment: @MatsPetersson Looks like I was just mistaken. I've removed the cast.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
int n = // whatever
int i = 0;
int* output = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*n);

for(i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    output[i] = i;
}
```

Don't forget to `free(output);` when you don't need it anymore.

EDIT: Made it C.

Comment: Was not clear from the question. Seen tag after your comment. :)

Answer (score 0):

If 'n' is changing during runtime, then you could use malloc like suggested in the comments.  Then check if you need more space, then automatically realloc more space should it be needed